# How do I handle twitter fail whale in JSONP

Tags: twitter, jsonp

I load

`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=formatTweets&q=somehashTag&timestamp="+new Date().getTime();`

I suddenly got

```
Error: illegal character
Source File: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=formatTweets&q=sunshine&timestamp=1305631097599
Line: 1, Column: 13
Source Code:
formatTweets(�
```

because twitter sent me a fail whale.

Can you think of a way to detect and handle this?

Here is my invocation:

```
function loadTweets() {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=formatTweets&q="+hashTag+"&timestamp="+new Date().getTime();
  head[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19173/210774) which had some interesting answers.  To summarize, one approach is to wrap all errors returned by the server in JSON, and another [provides a link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) to a nice looking reinterpretation of jQuery's JSONP implementation.

Comment: I could not find my twitter code, but I assume it will work. Thanks