# Sencha Touch JSONP error

Tags: twitter, jsonp, mobile-website, sencha-touch

EDIT:

I came across a confirmation of what I suspected:  Using the twitter search API with JSONP causes the problem in isolation, so it seems that something is going wrong with Twitter.

See:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23jimromeisburning&callback=dog

About 3/5 times, as of 3:44PM CT on 14 June, Twitter returns garbage.  The rest of the time, it returns a valid javascript function call.

---

I'm using Sencha Touch to make a JSONP request to the Twitter search API, and about 1/100 times, I'm getting a javascript error that kills further polling:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

So far I've tried the following with no leads:

1. Wrapping the call to Ext.util.JSONP.request({}) in a try/catch block.  Doesn't catch the error (presumably because it's being called from a script tag in an iframe)
2. Dumping the `query` parameter passed into JSONP.request to make sure that it's valid.  It is.
3. Looking for a pattern-- it seems to happen at unexpected times.  Could be the very first request, or it could be 100 requests down the line.

My best guess is that Twitter is sending back garbage some of the time.  That's ok, I just need a way to handle that error.  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, Sencha Touch doesn't have any built-in error handling for its JSONP requests.

Have you seen anything like this before?  Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Here's what the ornery JSONP script response looks like:

```
Ext.util.JSONP.callback(�Řo�6ǿ
�`)֥��k�em��+�`�
-�-��RT��w�ɖ���$v�-A^ґ���Ow�|�4Tua*+����ת����Ⱥ��VbšҐ�֡5Ҫ/
芒�[�o�ƌ��NǌE9褪���*��N3�1j;QRǏ®T��E�r4��S
�@��w|��!a.���ġ�%�����@��*����>Z8^_h��녾z>u]�E��ϸ�V��u�k&#@k
)Hc}=���;o%�.
�׍���L��5�T�B*�?������{���꒼z�M���.}/dm�=���곒5i�KA��y����Q�n���n����
Һ�x��̼R�N���q�k��<�\+s�*���&[��DCњH�WE�Ƴ���uhj�ڼ����ȋ��,t"�>�'����o�VnK��ⳍ�\�p,'9�
��:~{��"���8n�    
�x�ͫK���C�mx(�<�
����3>������B]A_�L�+=�%fY�*1��/���wO�vc�Z8d=)̦1����߳35����-F����.f���D|�.z6����Xs��s\愶  ���M*Z�D�� �7ڈ�)ϗ    cA�^9N�n�aN@�w�/^
P��¸-�E�$R�����<�K�n�3A3���L+�mI��vՃ�0Ǎ}o���Q��4�����=e��n�q8��ģ�����.�C)s=�:+>�O�h9�C2Q5Y���PA����*�3y1�t�`���g��WǠ�YB�O�/�{+.�[����,ߴ��/�yQ�<t(���|ߥ�G����ݾ�b��ijBS�9��.E�>�D%�I���jz�켻0�q��0`Q��.��.�>88�춖��(i4fȻgW@�aI*�������#���z�j�\5g��\�n���e���c��7�o��w�z�,�|/��+�N�����}�z+v����nd�
NY�R��o��    }��hĚ�;��g�D2��9�����:-e�����^@Ua���j2C��#�U���k�9���I�'�ܐ���/H3�q(��d�<�$����q~͛5��}��V�ft�'U'{���0�����Ø��sC?|B��0I���B�E] %�c��S���6LC�x�Y�EQT�*�Akr��÷OyOn��N�7iSkW` �F�q�!�����+,[���I��1
�i�3C*����_��h�K �� ^�{�V|YìM�7ŬW�t��'��ek��y�lr�l�WM)Đ�>�O���F,`�w��r��6�a�X����B�n�2t�O\�R7��O�n���!`�@
M� i���MU]5_�k�TMR�� 'Z��Y��C�Sn�q.�V��";d�`x��k Β��Mr��/�����٬A��Fq�B|L���>+,B0��R��K�����˵u�_~縫}��Zw����E���7�K����:.�i�n%��4l�/F���������5_�����);
```

Comment: Looks like this is a problem over at Twitter HQ.

After posting in the Google group, I got this:

> Thanks for all the extra info, folks
> -- this is very useful and I've now got a reproducible case. We'll look
> into this.
> 
> Thanks! @episod - Taylor Singletary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6030022/210774) in which the OP was encountering fail whales while using the search API.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6030022/210774) which had some interesting answers regarding error handling in JSONP.  To summarize, one approach is to wrap all errors returned by the server in JSON, and another [provides a link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) to jQuery-JSONP, a nice looking reinterpretation of jQuery's JSONP implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. You would need to override the `callback` method in the `Ext.util.JSONP` class, and wrap the line which calls the callback, in a  try/catch block. Then in the catch block try and call an `errorCallback` (which you need to define in your actual JSONP request).

```
Ext.util.JSONP.callback = function(json) {
    try {
        this.current.callback.call(this.current.scope, json);
    } catch(e) {
        this.current.errorCallback.call(this.current.scope);
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(this.current.script);
    this.next();
};
```

Comment: Great idea-- I gave it a go. I tried changing the Sencha source and overriding it in my code, and it looks like it never makes it to the Ext.util.JSONP.callback method.  The error is taking place in the JSONP implementation (because Twitter is shooting out garbage).

Comment: I've got a hacky sort of solution on a tip from someone on the google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/X7J_e9bOY-o) and it solved my problem.

You can use window.onerror(function() {}) to catch the error (and any others, unfortunately) and execute code that will get you past the issue.

Comment: Yeah, Twitter error. Because of the nature of JSONP (it inserts a <script> tag with the source being the URL you specify), there isn't a nice way you can catch this. I suggest that you create a timer for 5 seconds, or something similar, that gets cancelled if the callback returns. If not, then call a failure method.

Comment: I hear this is still an issue for folks doing this-- in case this helps someone, another solution that would make sense is using an iframe + timeout on ie < 9.